Error with schema table not connecting to express server
I am trying to set up a backend express API to display contact details on a contacts us page and then save the details from the form into my DB but i keep getting an error status 500 and the following error in my server
error saving data: error: relation "test" does not exist
    at /Users/server/node_modules/pg-pool/index.js:45:11
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async /Users/server/server.js:27:5 {

Here is my server
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 8080
const db = require('./db')

app.use(express.json())

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


app.get('/api/contact', (req, res) => {
  res.json({
        header: "Contact Us",
        body: " We've been around since 2013.",
        phone: "(123) 456-7890",
        email: "support@.com",
        postalAddress: "1234 Property Lane, Suite 567, Citytown, ST 12345",
        businessHours: "Monday - Friday, 9 AM - 5 PM"
  })
})

app.post('/api/submit', async (req, res) => {
  const { firstName, lastName, email, phone, message } = req.body;

  try {
    await db.query(
      'INSERT INTO test (first_name, last_name, email, phone_number, message) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)',
      [firstName, lastName, email, phone, message]
    )
    res.status(200).json({message: 'form submitted'})
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error saving data:', error);
    res.status(500).json({error: 'an erorr occured'})
  }
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`server listening on port ${port}`);
})

DB.js file
const pg = require('pg');
require('dotenv').config();

const db = new pg.Pool({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
});

module.exports = db;

env.
DATABASE_URL='postgresql://localhost:5432/contact_test'

I have double checked my DB and table and no syntax error and have dropped the table and re created . I also have manually added records in psql which works but when testing through postman with the http://localhost:8080/api/submit endpoint i keep getting the same error. Can I please get some help. Thanks.

check database name thoroughly also user name and role permissions. Also try hardcoding connection data, like pg.Pool({ host: 'localhost', port: 5432, database: 'contact_test'  })

Thank you. This helped resolve the issue.

Make sure your mongodb configs are correct. I don't see configs in your code. maybe you should try this codes to config and connect your database:


const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const connectD = async () => {
  try {
    //throw error
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.*DATABASE_LOCAL/DATABASEURL*);
    console.log(
      `connected to database ${mongoose.connection.host} `
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("DB Error", error);
  }
};
module.exports = connectD;



then in your server file:


const connectD = require("./db");

//connect database
connectD();




OP is using postgres not mongo db
